# How to fix Meteor being unreliable on mobile

Tags: ios, mobile, meteor

I'm not even sure where to start. I have a relatively simple meteor app (http://www.vertexshaderart.com). It's using iron router for routes. The main route `/` seems like a pretty normal situation. Show the 8 newest posts. Show the 8 most liked posts `sort: {likes: -1}`.

When I try to view on my phone it only works about 1 out 5 times, maybe less. The site shows up, the main template is clearly rendered and at least one child rendered but the templates waiting for data never show up. They have `{{#if Template.subscriptionsReady}}` wrappers. Or rather the parts inside the wrapper never show up. I'm guessing the subscriptions never complete on mobile for some reason. In fact the entire 10+ minutes I've been typing and editing this response I've had my phone sitting beside my computer trying to load the page. It's been sitting there loading for > 10 mins, the data spinner in the iOS status bar spinning constantly.

But, when I try to debug it it always works (or at least so far). It works fine in the iPhone Simulator. It works fine if I connect directly to my dev machine over WiFi. Like I said it works fine 1 or of 5 times or so on mobile. I've tried connecting to a debugger USB and then remote debug Safari but it always seems to work when I do that.

You might think it's a bad mobile connection but every other site I view seems to work just fine. Slashdot, Ars, Hackernews, GMail (the website), Facebook's website (not app), Reddit. Etc.

Any idea how I can debug this? Or is this a known issue?

Here's my code

```
Router.route('/', {
  template: 'front',
});
```

-

```
<template name="front">
  <header>
    <div>
        <div class="buttons">
            {{> userinfosignin}}
        </div>
        {{> logo}}
    </div>
  </header>
  <div class="container">
     <div class="gallery">
         {{> artselection sort="newest" limit="8"}}
         {{> artselection sort="popular" limit="8"}}
     </div>
  </div>

<template name="artselection">
   <div class="sortcriteria">
       <div class="title">
           <div>{{sort}}:</div><div class="right"> <a href="/gallery/1/?sort={{sort}}">see all</a></div>
       </div>
       <div class="artgrid">
           {{#if Template.subscriptionsReady}}
             {{#each art}}
               {{> artpiece}}
             {{/each}}
           {{/if}}
       </div>
   </div>
</template>

<template name="artpiece">

<div class="artpiece">
    <a href="/art/{{_id}}">
      <img class="thumbnail" src="{{screenshotLink.url}}" />
    </a>
    <div class="galleryinfo">
        <div class="galleryname">
            <a href="/art/{{_id}}">&ldquo;{{name}}&rdquo;</a>
            <a href="/user/{{username}}">by: {{username}}</a>
        </div>
        <div>
            <a href="/art/{{_id}}">
              <span class="views">{{views}}</span><span class="likes">{{likes}}</span>
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</template>
```

I can see all of that gets rendered except the part inside the `{{if Template.subscriptionsReady}}`

Here's the code for that template

```
  // in a client section
  Template.artselection.onCreated(function() {
    var instance = this;
    instance.autorun(function() {
      var sort = getSortingType(instance.data.sort);
      instance.subscribe('artSelection', sort, parseInt(instance.data.limit));
    });
  });

  Template.artselection.helpers({
    art: function() {
      var instance = Template.instance();
      var sortField = getSortingType(instance.data.sort);
      var sort = {};
      sort[sortField] = -1;
      var options = {
        sort: sort,
        limit: parseInt(instance.data.limit),
      };
      return Art.find({}, options);
    },
  });

  // in a sever section
  Meteor.publish("artSelection", function(sortField, limit) {
    var find = {
      private: {$ne: true},
    };
    var sort = {};
    sort[sortField] = -1;
    var options = {
      fields: {settings: false},
      sort: sort,
      limit: limit,
    };
    return Art.find(find, options);
  });

  function getSortingType(sort) {
    switch (sort) {
      case "mostviewed":
        return "views";
      case "newest":
        return "modifiedAt";
      case "popular":
      default:
        return "likes";
    }
  }
```

Note: `Art` is a collection that's pretty much the same as `Posts` in any tutorial. The data is small. Just `_id`, `username`, `owner`, `title`, `createdAt`, `modifiedAt`, `likes`, `views`, `hasSound`. That's about it and one field `settings` which is a string which is at most 2-3k but I'm excluding that field in the publish method. In fact, checking the frames in the Chrome debugger when viewing on desktop it looks like only about 12k of data is sent down over the websocket before the front page is completely rendered. In other words, this isn't an issue of sending lots of data.

I'm on Meteor 1.2.1.

## Update

I figured out the issue is actually [Chrome's Data Saver feature](https://developer.chrome.com/multidevice/data-compression). I made the bad assumption that since both are WebKit under the hood that remote debugging on Safari would help me find the issue but Chrome is doing fancy networking behind the scenes of it's embedded WebKit view. Turning off the data saver feature and it started working.

According to Google you can disable the data saver feature on the server side by adding the header

```
Cache-Control: no-transform
```

So for now I'll try adding that header to my site. Otherwise I'm pretty sure google wants it to just work so I've [filed a bug](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=553828)

Answer (score 0):

I am absolutely not sure that it will solve your problem, but have you try the "waitOn" feature of iron router (just to help you to locate the problem) ?

Apparently, you would like to be sure that your subscription to your data has been fully established with this block:

```
      {{#if Template.subscriptionsReady}}
         {{#each art}}
           {{> artpiece}}
         {{/each}}
       {{/if}}
```

Could your try to create a route pointing to your template having the issue, and check if the data are loading on this route ?

Something like the following code and see if the problem persists ?

```
Router.route('/art_selection', {
  name: 'artselection',
  waitOn: function () { return Meteor.subscribe('artSelection'); },
  data: function () {
    return {
      art: Art.find(),
    }
  }
});
```

If it is working well on the route and not on your main page, then I guess your template is not waiting your subscription to be ready the first time it renders, and do not re-render after the subscription has been completed.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. It turned out to be Chrome iOS (and Android?) See above